# geometry nodes > rotation of grid instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

The instances of a grid rotate wrongly.
I want a rotation only in the y direction but the rotation is done in the x and y direction.
[image]

I must be something essential that I'm doing wrong...
How do I pass on the distance value from the proximity node as a y vector value?

Thx!

Comment: A note in addition to @Chris' answer: _Map Range->Separate XYZ_ casts a `Float` to a `Vector`, which will fill X,Y and Z of the vector with the same float. Then _SeparateXYZ(Y)->Rotation_ does it again,. You could replace _Separate XYZ_ with _Combine XYZ_ .

Answer (score 1):

try this node tree:

[image]

[image]

several things you should know:

- Blender and GN are working internally with radians, not degrees. So if you want to rotate a half circle, the correct value is Pi, not 180 degrees.
- the map range node of type float outputs a float. So it makes no sense to separate a float to xyz value.
- you want to use the combine xyz value - which takes 3 floats and makes a vector out of them

Hint: you can enter "pi" in a value field - Blender knows it

Hint 2: you can enter "tau" in a value field - which is 2 * pi

Comment: This indeed solves my issue. Thanks Chris!

Comment: if my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx